# Is BigInteger efficient compared to long?

Tags: java, performance, biginteger

I am implementation a distributed key-value store in Java. I need to save a timestamp for each key. Since I want to have a large of number of keys in the system, I decided to use `BigInteger` instead of `long`, but I am concerned about its efficiency.

Note that I don't have any multiplication, I only used `addition` and `comparTo`. 
So do you think the `BigInteger` is significantly less efficient than `long`?

It is the first time that I am trying `BigInteger`, is there any other concern comparing to `long`?

Comment: What sort of efficiency? Speed or memory or both? Have you tested BigInteger vs. long in your actual application?

Comment: How many keys do you expect that you think `2^64` isn't enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748028/long-vs-biginteger | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498363/performance-implications-of-using-java-biginteger-for-a-huge-bitmask | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603513/increasing-javas-biginteger-performance

Comment: You're not going to need more that 2^64 keys in your system.  I guarantee it.

Comment: You're using the timestamp for the key? At what precision, and what happens if multiple keys come in at the same time? Anyway, a long can fit about 585 years' worth of nanoseconds, so it's going to be more than enough. (Btw, that yields my favorite bit of JavaDoc in the JDK: a warning that calculating difference in [System.nanoTime() will overflow if your app runs for more than 292 years](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--).)

Comment: Have you considered using, err, a `Timestamp`?

Comment: Or a UUID, possibly time-based?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Do we have unsigned long in java? By a long I can have 2^63-1.

Note that my timestamps are lamport clocks (logical clocks), so they are basically simple counters.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf Even that gives you ~292 years' worth of nanoseconds (see my fun JavaDoc link from above). But you can always just treat the `long` as 64 bits as representing an unsigned number. Things like toStringing and inequality comparisons won't work out of the box, but Guava has a couple classes to help with that: [`UnsignedLong`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.html) gives you a "boxed"-style instance, whereas `UnsignedLongs` (note the plural) provides static method calls that work on longs.

Comment: Mmmm..., so if the users of my system, add 1000,000,000 keys per second, the system works fine for 292 years. Good ^_^

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf If you allow numbers to go negative, they won't duplicate/overlap for another 292 years.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf You could limit yourself to 10 million keys per second in which case you get 29,200 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `BigInteger` needs more memory than a `long`, and because it is not a primitive type, it is also slower. I would only use it when you need more digits than a long can provide.

For your purposes, a `long` should be sufficient (and more efficient), as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

## `Instant`

If you want a timestamp, we already have a class for that: [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

In Java 8 the current moment is captured with a resolution up to milliseconds. In Java 9 a new implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) captures the current moment up to the full nanosecond resolution, depending on your computer clock hardware.

## UUID

But if you want to identify objects across distributed systems, use the type invented for just that purpose: [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). This type is defined in official standards. Made of a 128-bit value, basically an unimaginably large number, but certain bits have certain meanings.

For human reading, a hex string is generated in a canonical format.

Java includes a [`UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class to represent such values. Stored internally as a pair of 64-bit `long` numbers in the OpenJDK implementation as I recall.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID() ;
String hex = uuid.toString() ;
```

## `BigInteger` > `long`

And to answer your direct issue, `BigInteger` is designed to represent ginormous numbers, not designed for efficiency. A `long` primitive (64-bit number) uses much less memory since it lacks the overhead of a class & object and the machinery for representing and operating on ginormous numbers that may be much larger than fit into CPU registers. And operations on a `long` execute much faster.

So, when you do not need the features of `BigInteger`, stick with `long` primitive.